# How can i record user audio in my django chat app?

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, audio-recording, voice-recording

I have a simple chat app like WhatsApp, but users are complaining for not being able to record a voice message as WhatsApp or messenger, I have been searching for over a week but didn't find anything that could help me, I have the audio model ready but what I can't do is record audio from my app directly instead of the user having to leave the website to record audio and save it as a file and then send it.
Here is my models.py

```
class Message(models.Model):
    chat_box = models.ForeignKey(
        ChatBox, related_name='chat_box', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    message_sender = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name='message_sender', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(
        upload_to='social_group_message_images', blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='social/friend_message_images', blank=True, null=True)
    audio = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='social/friend_message_audio', blank=True, null=True)
    video = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='social/friend_message_video', blank=True, null=True)
```

my views.py (I'm going to change it later to make it work with ajax):

```
def send_friend_file_message(request, pk):
friend = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
friend = get_object_or_404(User, pk=pk)
chat_box = ChatBox.objects.filter(
    user_1=request.user, user_2=friend).first()
if not chat_box:
    chat_box = ChatBox.objects.filter(
        user_1=friend, user_2=request.user).first()

message = Message(chat_box=chat_box, message_sender=request.user,
                  file=request.FILES.get('file'), image=request.FILES.get('image'), video=request.FILES.get('video'), audio=request.FILES.get('audio'))
message.save()
return redirect('social:chat_friend', pk=pk)
```

Finally the html that sends document/video/AUDIO messages:

```
<div class="modal-body">
            <div>
                <!-- Send file -->
                <form action="{% url 'social:send_friend_file_message' friend.id %}" method="post"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data" id="sendFileForm">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input type="file" name="file" id="uploadFile" class="from-file" accept="*">

                    <input type="file" name="image" id="uploadImage" class="from-file" accept="image/*">
                    <input type="file" name="video" id="uploadVideo" class="from-file" accept="video/*"
                        style="display:none;" onchange="document.querySelector('#sendFileForm').submit()">
                    <input type="file" name="audio" id="uploadAudio" class="from-file" accept="audio/*"
                        style="display:none;" onchange="document.querySelector('#sendFileForm').submit()">
                </form>
                <span class="mr-3 btn d-inline" id="displayUploadFile">
                    <i class="far fa-file" style="font-size:24px"></i> Document
                </span>
                <!-- Send image -->
                <span class="btn" id="displayUploadImage">
                    <i class="far fa-image" style="font-size:24px"></i> Image
                </span>
                <!-- Send video -->
                <span class="btn" onclick="document.querySelector('#uploadVideo').click()">
                    <i class="fas fa-video" style="font-size:24px"></i> Video
                </span>
                <!-- Audio -->
                <span class="btn" onclick="document.querySelector('#uploadAudio').click()">
                    <i class="fas fa-headphones-alt" style="font-size:24px"></i> Audio
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: have a look at [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API) or [Google Web Fundamentals](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio)

Comment: Now I'm at where I was before, recording user input and displaying it to him, but how can I send that rec to Django to save it? what should I pass in the data param in my ajax request to send the audio to Django??

Comment: Go through this [tutorial](https://www.google.com/amp/s/blog.addpipe.com/using-recorder-js-to-capture-wav-audio-in-your-html5-web-site/amp/). If you have completed the recording part, just skip to upload part. Have fun